# Index out of Range in Spark MLLIB K-means with TFIDF for Text clutsering

Tags: python, algorithm, apache-spark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to run k-means using spark MLlib but I am getting Index out of range error.

I've splitted my very small sample input file and the output is like this:-

```
['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'earth']
['what', 'are', 'you', 'trying', 'to', 'do']
['trying', 'to', 'learn', 'something']
['I', 'am', 'new', 'at', 'this', 'thing']
['what', 'about', 'you']
```

Now I'am using TFIDF code given by spark to have sparse representation. Output is :-

```
(1048576,[50570,432125,629096,921177,928731],  [1.09861228867,1.09861228867,0.69314718056,1.09861228867,1.09861228867])
(1048576,[110522,521365,697409,725041,749730,962395],[0.69314718056,1.09861228867,1.09861228867,0.69314718056,0.69314718056,0.69314718056])
(1048576,[4471,725041,850325,962395],[1.09861228867,0.69314718056,1.09861228867,0.69314718056])
(1048576,[36748,36757,84721,167368,629096,704697],[1.09861228867,1.09861228867,1.09861228867,1.09861228867,0.69314718056,1.09861228867])
(1048576,[110522,220898,749730],[0.69314718056,1.09861228867,0.69314718056])
```

And now I am running the k means algorithm given by MLlib in spark:-

```
clusters = KMeans.train(tfidf_vectors, 2, maxIterations=10)  

def error(point):
    center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)]
    return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point - center)]))

WSSSE = tfidf_vectors.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
print("Within Set Sum of Squared Error = " + str(WSSSE))

clusters.save(sc, "myModelPath")
sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

But I am getting Index out of range error at WSSSE step.
what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does your output for `clusters` look like?

Comment: I am not sure how to look at the output. I've a bunch of file in myModelPath folder which was created after running the program. If you can tell me which file, then I can get back to you. And clusters is not iterable so couldn't print it.

Answer (score 1):

I've already encountered a similar problem today and it <s>looks like</s> [is a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10973). TFIDF creates `SparseVectors` like this:

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
>>> sv = Vectors.sparse(5, {1: 3})
```

and accessing value using index larger than an index of the last non-zero value leads to an exception:

```
>>> sv[0]
0.0
>>> sv[1]
3.0
>>> sv[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Quick, although not very efficient, workaround is to convert `SparseVector` to NumPy array:

```
def error(point):                                                         
    center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)]
    return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point.toArray() - center)]))
```